# chromium-compact-language-detector Django

Tags: python, django, chromium, language-detection

I am using the chromium-compact-language-detector to detect language but it is unable to detect Japanese in the string.

```
text = '1/15 HR Div.Q&CS Dept. 全体MTG 開催
1月15日(水)、赤溜オーディトリアムにてHR Div.Q&CS Dept.の全体MTGが開催されました。 ' 

cld.detect(smart_str(text), pickSummaryLanguage=True, removeWeakMatches=False)

output: ('ENGLISH', 'en', True, 11, [('ENGLISH', 'en', 100, 0.8103727714748784)])
```

Suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to first encode that japanese string as UTF8, eg.
Try This :

```
import codecs
import cld
cld.detect(codecs.getencoder('UTF-8')(u'1/15 HR Div.Q&CS Dept. 全体MTG 開催1月15日(水)、赤溜オーディトリアムにてHR Div.Q&CS Dept.の全体MTGが開催されました。 ')[0])
```

I think `cld` can't detect japanese lang . New version of it is available called `cld2` . Check here : `https://code.google.com/p/cld2/wiki/CLD2FullVersion`

Comment: I tried your way but still it is not giving Japanese.          output : ('ENGLISH', 'en', True, 11, [('ENGLISH', 'en', 100, 0.8103727714748784)])

Comment: Try putting that text in html file and open it in chromium . Its detect or not .

Comment: No it is not detecting it in chromium.

Comment: hmmm . Chromium browser bug . you can open ticket there if u want. ;) .

Comment: There is something weird if I remove "1/15 HR Div.Q&CS Dept." from the the main string "1/15 HR Div.Q&CS Dept. 全体MTG 開催

1月15日(水)、赤溜オーディトリアムにてHR Div.Q&CS Dept.の全体MTGが開催されました。" ,CLD is able to detect Japanese , CLD output: ('Japanese', 'ja', True, 80, [('Japanese', 'ja', 80, 162.0), ('ENGLISH', 'en', 20, 0.8103727714748784)])

Comment: A new version of the CLD is added called 'cld2' . it can detect more language . `https://code.google.com/p/cld2/wiki/CLD2FullVersion`

Comment: Is CLD2 stable or it is still in Beta ?